# Get MAX 5 items from a grouped List with LINQ and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, group-by

I have a grouped List of items, grouped by the name.

So for example I have item[0] that has 4 items, item[1] that has 6 items, item [2] that has 10 items etc.

Now I want to get Max 5 items, ie those that have the most items inside this GroupedList.

I am getting the grouped list as follows :-

```
IEnumerable<List<AuditLog>> auditLogsGouped = auditLogs.GroupBy(x =>    x.EntityValue).Select(grp => grp.ToList());
```

How can I get the MAX 5 items from this list?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do a trick for you :

```
auditLogsGouped.OrderBy(x=>x.Count).Reverse().Take(5);
```

or better:

```
auditLogsGouped.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count).Take(5);
```

Comment: OrderByDescending perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `Enumerable.Take`. Here's the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) and the relevant portion:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Take<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
  int count
)
```

> Take enumerates source and yields elements until count
>   elements have been yielded or source contains no more elements. If
>   count exceeds the number of elements in source, all elements of source
>   are returned.

So this should do what you want by just calling `.Take(5)`